# mono - c# - System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider could not be loaded, used in System.Core

Tags: c#, mono, aescryptoserviceprovider

I use mono to execute console application on unix machine.
When i start application I got error

```
System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider could not be loaded, used in System.Core
```

Inside my app I use AesCryptoServiceProvider class of System.Security namespace.

On Windows machine all work fine.

net framework is 3.5

mono version

```
Mono JIT compiler version 1.2.6 (tarball)
Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC)
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
```

Comment: OMG, please, get a newer version!!! that's from 10 years ago!!!

Comment: I can't. The customer does not allow changes to the installed software.

Comment: Then you can't do nothing, it will never work... Maybe you can switch to .net Core? if it has enough functionality for your project you can create a self contained application which doesn't needs any framework installed (no need for .net Framework nor mono).

Answer (score 0):

AesCryptoServiceProvider is not in mono 1.2.6.

It is necessary to use different algorimitmi as TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider